# Is there a way to enable/disable multifactor authentication for individual users in Azure AD B2C tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

We've got an MVC application connected with azure AD B2C tenant for authentication. We need to allow MFA for siging in the users, I can see that we can easily enable/disable the MFA from User Flow properties. 
Please refer to [User Flow properties - MFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMHOj.png).

However, above setting is applied for all the users, and we want to enable/disable the MFA for individual users based on their preference selected from our application. Is there a way to do so ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Nitin Gupta

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom). You can save user preference as an extension attribute and based on presence of it, invoke MFA. In Custom policies you can tweak rules to suit custom needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try to see if I can get it work.

Thanks again.

Comment: let me know if you need examples or help

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal could you please share an example if you have it?